# Custom filter and navigation issues

Tags: support, custom-filter, navigation

I have a custom filter that lists the questions I'm interested in and it works fine. However, if I click into a specific question in that list and then use my browser back button to return to the list, it doesn't return me to the same place or, apparently, the same list. This behaviour is particularly apparent when I'm not on the 1st page of the list.

As an example, I have just selected a question in the middle of the list of page 2 - so that even if new questions are added before I return to the list this question should still be on the same page at least - and when I go back to the list from this question, the question is no longer visible.

If I re-run my custom filter and go back to that page then I can see the question. The URL before and after I click on a specific question and then return to the list seem to be the same. In case it is relevant, I use the Chrome browser.

Any thoughts about what is causing this inconsistent behaviour?

(Custom filter I click on to generate this list can be seen on the right of the screenshots below)

Page 2 before I click on an individual question:[image: Before]

Page 2 after I click the back arrow from the individual question: [image: After]

Comment: Assuming it is the personalised home page you are looking at, it is normal behaviour that the list of questions is not the same on page refreshes. If you want the list to stay the same, use the open in a new tab feature of your browser.

Comment: Its not a personalised home page, its a custom filter being run

Comment: Try a different browser. I noticed that the "back" button behaves differently for [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/) than it does for [Mozilla Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/). With _Chrome_ the "back" button reloads the page but with _Firefox_ it doesn't. So I would say it's a browser issue and not a problem with the _stackoverflow_ Web site.

Comment: Ah ok it's a search, I was confused and thought you had set tag filters.